# I need the design like this in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Need to design to show first country list(State and District list should be hide) and when I click on a particular country, and expand a list about the states list (for example if we take India, US, UK countries and I click India and its shows the state list which belongs to India) and if I click to expand the particular state and expand district list which belong to particular state.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 50%; height: 50%">
            <div>
                <ul ng-repeat="country in treedata.countrieslist">
                    <li>
                        <button ng-show="!country.isExpanded" ng-click="country.isExpanded=!country.isExpanded">+</button>
                        <button ng-show="country.isExpanded" ng-click="country.isExpanded=!country.isExpanded">-</button>
                        {{country.CountryName}}
                        <ul ng-repeat="state in treedata.getStateList(country.CountryId)" ng-show="country.isExpanded">
                            <li>
                                <button ng-show="!state.isExpanded" ng-click="state.isExpanded=!state.isExpanded">+</button>
                                <button ng-show="state.isExpanded" ng-click="state.isExpanded=!state.isExpanded">-</button>
                                {{state.StateName}}
                                <ul ng-repeat="district in treedata.getDistrictList(state.StateId)" ng-show="state.isExpanded">
                                    <li>{{district.DistrictName}}
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Note : i'm retrieving the data from the server with ajax call get method.
Please help me out with your valuable solution with AngularJS

EDIT:

```
$http.get('/ExpandView/GetCountriesList/').success(function (data) {
            treedata.countrieslist = data;
    });
    treedata.getStateList = function (id) {
        $http.get('/ExpandView/GetStatesList/').success(function (data) {
            treedata.states = data;
        });
    }

    $http.get('/ExpandView/GetDistrictsList/').success(function (data) {
        treedata.districts = data;
    });

    treedata.getStateList = function (id) {
        return treedata.states.filter(function (p) {
            return p.CountryId == id;
        });
    }
    treedata.getDistrictList = function (id) {
        return treedata.districts.filter(function (p) {
            return p.stateid == id;
        });
    }
```

this functionality not working. Please suggest me.

Comment: I flagged this as off topic, recommending a tutorial. You are asking us to basically translate code for you. What have you tried so far? Can you provide us with _any_ (not pseudo) code you have in AngularJS?

Comment: Please click "edit" and append that to your _question_. Also use correct code formatting. My flag and downvote still stands, however

Comment: @Jagan: Kindly create a fiddle with what you have done and what you want. people will be able to help you more easily that way.

Comment: @Jagan Edit your post and put your code IN the post with proper formatting please.

Answer (score -2):

i have created one sample fiddle for you for you to see how this country to state thing will work in angular js [SEE HERE](http://goo.gl/XbRu5z)

so the exact solution would be [this one](http://learnit.visrosoftware.com/try/JSx4pZpM)

Comment: I created the fiddle                                                           http://jsfiddle.net/jhw9hn4o/

Comment: Thanks :) but i need to display like a tree structre...  if i click india under india show the states of Punjab and Amirthsir and should not show for other countries

Comment: @Jagan okay i have done it the same way look here http://goo.gl/lQXEnn  this will show tree like structure

Comment: Thanks and same as if i click the state and district need to display for particular state

Comment: Ya its correct. but the thing is that i need to give the expand and collapse buttons for the list type

Comment: @Jagan this is all logic goes here. so with isExpanded variable you can manage the visibility of plus icon or minus icon and it will be customizable

Comment: Can you send me the clear solution for that with add and plus icon...... http://learnit.visrosoftware.com/try/IQrXNEbz

Comment: @Jagan here you get final solution http://learnit.visrosoftware.com/try/sJ1Lnl4p  with plus and minus sign

Comment: Thanks for your Great Help... please any chance to remove/hide the bullet on every list. I need only + or - icons

Comment: I have a doubt about and calling in angular ajax post back call and passing parameter as id but it's result is not coming and how to with the filter... Please suggest me

Comment: HI Averyone I need right click context menu for every list....   Please follow the below URL                 http://learnit.visrosoftware.com/try/sJ1Lnl4p